# Remove item from object that does not have value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not want to render a label if it does not have a value.

Object
{
equip1: "888"
equip2: ""
equip3: ""
equip4: ""
equip5: ""
equip6: ""
equip7: ""}

Template:

```
 <% var equipment = data.equipData                      
_.each(equipment, function(numUnits, equipName){%>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="equipCatagory">{{equipName}}</label></td>
   <td>{{numUnits}}</td>
 </tr>
 <% }) %>
```

What is the best way to not show a label if numUnits is empty?

Comment: `if ( numUnits == "" ) return` mayne ?

Comment: This is neither JavaScript nor jQuery! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a condition to the _.each callback function:

```
 <% var equipment = data.equipData                      
_.each(equipment, function(numUnits, equipName){
if(!numUnits) return;
%>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="equipCatagory">{{equipName}}</label></td>
   <td>{{numUnits}}</td>
 </tr>
 <% }) %>
```

Comment: May you check it as "Accept answer?"